# ¿como puedo construir un HttpContext estableciendo una dirección IP

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Actualmente estoy construyendo una prueba unitaria que prueba un metodo en mi web API, pero este metodo, lo que hace es obtener una ip, pero no es posible por que el context va null..

Alguien sabe como establecer `HttpContext` pasandole una dirección IP para efectos de pruebas unitarias?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de buscar me encontre con una Framework de burlas llamado [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) la cual me permite realizar burlar a las clases, por ejemplo:

```
// Multiple setups on a single mock and its recursive mocks
ControllerContext context = Mock.Of<ControllerContext>(ctx =>
ctx.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == "kzu" &&
ctx.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated == true &&
ctx.HttpContext.Request.Url == new Uri("http://moqthis.com") &&
ctx.HttpContext.Response.ContentType == "application/xml");
```

La forma en la que pude crear un `HttpContext` fue de la siguiente manera:

```
string pUrl = string.Empty;
string pIp = string.Empty;
bool pEstaAutenticado = false;
var uri = new Uri(pUrl);
fakeRequestBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
fakeContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
fakeRequestBase.Setup(pRequest => pRequest.UserHostAddress).Returns(pIp);
fakeRequestBase.Setup(pRequest => pRequest.Url).Returns(uri);
fakeRequestBase.Setup(pRequest => pRequest.RawUrl).Returns(pUrl);
fakeRequestBase.Setup(pRequest => pRequest.IsAuthenticated).Returns(pEstaAutenticado);
fakeContextBase.Setup(pContext => pContext.Request).Returns(fakeRequestBase.Object);
```

> Tener en cuenta que el objeto `HttpContext` no se puede burlar, pera esto existe el objeto `HttpContextBase` que es una copia de `HttpContext` con la única diferencia de que `HttpContextBase` si se puede burlar.